# Qt - decode binary sequence from base64

Tags: c++, qt, base64

I'm trying to decode a base64-encoded string, which contains some binary data. The string sometimes contains only one character. Unfortunately, the function QByteArray::fromBase64() works only with larger input strings.

This code works for me for larger input strings:

```
QByteArray text = QByteArray::fromBase64("ykw8");

unsigned int val = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    val |= (text.data()[text.length() - i - 1] & 0xff)  << (i*8);
```

after that `val` contains 13257788, which is the correct data encoded in "ykw8". However, if I submit "u" as the argument of fromBase64(), the size of resulting array (`text`) is 0. The variable `val` therefore contains also 0, although it should be 46.

I have tried padding the input string, i. e. "u==" and similar, but the size of `text` was always 0.
So how do I get fromBase64() decode short strings properly?

Comment: Are you sure `"u"` is a correct base64 encoded string? Because `QByteArray::fromBase64()` skips things it cannot decode.

Comment: If you convert 46 to base64 using `QByteArray::toBase64()`, you get "Lg==". So it is likely that "u" is not a valid base64 encoded string (according to RFC 2045, to which Qt's implementation is based), as UmNyobe already commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on having "u" as base64 encoded result, the nearest valid base64 is "uA==". But it does not decode as 46 (00101110) but 184 (10111000) . Base64 needs a full 24bit groups to operate correctly. If there is not enough bits in the input, it is zero padded *on the right*. The first 6bit group is then "u" and the second is all zeros but it still has 2 bits from your original data, so it is not "=" padding but "A".

Read [RFC 2405](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt), chapter 6.8 "Base64 Content-Transfer-Encoding"

Comment: I realize that. I though base64 was just number converted to base 64 just like hex is in base 16. I was forced to write my own function for that.

Answer (score 1):

Because Qt doesn't check the validity of an input for base64 decoding, here is an example for testing if the string resembles a base64 format or not.

```
bool isB64(QString input){
    if(input.length() % 4 != 0)
        return false;
    if(QRegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9+/]+$").indexIn(input, QRegExp::CaretAtZero) == -1 &&
            QRegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9+/]+=$").indexIn(input, QRegExp::CaretAtZero) == -1 &&
            QRegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9+/]+==$").indexIn(input, QRegExp::CaretAtZero) == -1)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```